# Cannot Connect to Amazon AWS SQL Server Express database from Ubuntu SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, remote-access

I created an Amazon RDS database in SQL Server, created a custom security group with inbound rule type SQL Server protocal TCP Port "XXXX" Source "My PC's IP Address/32", allowed port "XXXX" over my firewall via "sudo ufw allow from any to any port "XXXX" proto tcp", successfully installed SQL Server on ubuntu via this tutorial: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-ms-sql-on-ubuntu/, and set 'public-accessibility' to 'no' in my AWS Database.

However, when I try to log in to my AWS Database from the command line via:

```
sqlcmd -S databasename.code.us-east-#.rds.amazonaws.com,XXXX -U username -P password -d DatabaseName
```

I get the error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x102.
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

I spelled everything correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about secuirty groups for the RDS?

Comment: You set the Publicly Accessible property to no? [I am having trouble connecting to my Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) DB instance.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check your network ACL's of your VPC and also make sure you have ephemeral ports allowed on your VPC ACL's.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports

Comment: Hello. I made my own ACL with input / output rules for my IP address and the subnet addresses and disabled the default one by selecting Deny all traffic input / output. I also added the ephemeral ports. I then set public accessibility to 'yes' and I can connect to my database. If public accessibility is set to no, do I need a site to site VPN?

Comment: Great. Yeah you will need site-to-site VPN if you turn off public accessibility.